# Please help me to find the mistake in query

Tags: sql, sqlite

Hye,

I have table AddClient which have data like this

```
      idClient  NameClient              Balance  Date

        CL-MK   Muhammad Kashif  CL-MK  9000    2016-10-01
        CL-MA   Asim  CL-MA             8000    2016-10-01
        CL-MQ   Qasim  CL-MQ            7000    2016-10-01
        CL-MS   Saim  CL-MS             1000    2016-10-01
        CL-MF   Fahad  CL-MF            3000    2016-10-01
        CL-MK   Muhammad Kashif  CL-MK          2016-10-01
        CL-MK   Muhammad Kashif  CL-MK          2016-10-01
        CL-MK   Muhammad Kashif  CL-MK          2016-10-01
        CL-MK   Muhammad Kashif  CL-MK          2016-10-01
        CL-MK   Muhammad Kashif  CL-MK          2016-10-01
        CL-MA   Asim  CL-MA                     2016-10-01
        CL-MA   Asim  CL-MA                     2016-10-01
        CL-MA   Asim  CL-MA                     2016-10-01
        CL-MA   Asim  CL-MA                     2016-10-01
        CL-MA   Asim  CL-MA                     2016-10-01
        CL-MQ   Qasim  CL-MQ                    2016-10-01
        CL-MQ   Qasim  CL-MQ                    2016-10-01
        CL-MQ   Qasim  CL-MQ                    2016-10-01
        CL-MQ   Qasim  CL-MQ                    2016-10-01
        CL-MQ   Qasim  CL-MQ                    2016-10-01
        CL-MS   Saim  CL-MS                     2016-10-01
        CL-MS   Saim  CL-MS                     2016-10-01
        CL-MS   Saim  CL-MS                     2016-10-01
        CL-MS   Saim  CL-MS                     2016-10-01
        CL-MS   Saim  CL-MS                     2016-10-01
        CL-MF   Fahad  CL-MF                    2016-10-01
        CL-MF   Fahad  CL-MF                    2016-10-01
        CL-MF   Fahad  CL-MF                    2016-10-01
        CL-MF   Fahad  CL-MF                    2016-10-01
        CL-MF   Fahad  CL-MF                    2016-10-01
        CL-MA   Asim  CL-MA                     2016-10-01
        CL-MA   Asim  CL-MA                     2016-10-01
        CL-MA   Asim  CL-MA                     2016-10-01
        CL-MA   Asim  CL-MA                     2016-10-01
        CL-MA   Asim  CL-MA                     2016-10-01
        CL-MK   Muhammad Kashif  CL-MK          2016-10-01
        CL-MK   Muhammad Kashif  CL-MK          2016-10-01
        CL-MK   Muhammad Kashif  CL-MK          2016-10-01
        CL-MK   Muhammad Kashif  CL-MK          2016-10-01
        CL-MK   Muhammad Kashif  CL-MK          2016-10-01
        CL-MF   Fahad  CL-MF                    2016-10-01
        CL-MF   Fahad  CL-MF                    2016-10-01
        CL-MF   Fahad  CL-MF                    2016-10-01
        CL-MF   Fahad  CL-MF                    2016-10-01
        CL-MF   Fahad  CL-MF                    2016-10-01
        CL-MQ   Qasim  CL-MQ                    2016-10-01
        CL-MQ   Qasim  CL-MQ                    2016-10-01
        CL-MQ   Qasim  CL-MQ                    2016-10-01
        CL-MQ   Qasim  CL-MQ                    2016-10-01
        CL-MQ   Qasim  CL-MQ                    2016-10-01
        CL-MA   Asim  CL-MA                     2016-10-01
        CL-MA   Asim  CL-MA                     2016-10-01
        CL-MA   Asim  CL-MA                     2016-10-01
        CL-MA   Asim  CL-MA                     2016-10-01
        CL-MA   Asim  CL-MA                     2016-10-01
        CL-MS   Saim  CL-MS                     2016-10-01
        CL-MS   Saim  CL-MS                     2016-10-01
        CL-MS   Saim  CL-MS                     2016-10-01
        CL-MS   Saim  CL-MS                     2016-10-01
        CL-MS   Saim  CL-MS                     2016-10-01
        CL-MF   Fahad  CL-MF                    2016-10-01
        CL-MF   Fahad  CL-MF                    2016-10-01
        CL-MF   Fahad  CL-MF                    2016-10-01
        CL-MF   Fahad  CL-MF                    2016-10-01
        CL-MF   Fahad  CL-MF                    2016-10-01
        CL-MF   Fahad  CL-MF                    2016-10-01
        CL-MF   Fahad  CL-MF                    2016-10-01
        CL-MF   Fahad  CL-MF                    2016-10-01
        CL-MA   Asim  CL-MA                     2016-10-01
        CL-MF   Fahad  CL-MF                    2016-10-01
        CL-MK   Muhammad Kashif  CL-MK          2016-10-01
        CL-MQ   Qasim  CL-MQ                    2016-10-01
        CL-MS   Saim  CL-MS                     2016-10-01
        CL-MQ   Qasim  CL-MQ                    2016-10-01
        CL-MQ   Qasim  CL-MQ                    2016-10-01
        CL-MQ   Qasim  CL-MQ                    2016-10-01
        CL-MA   Asim  CL-MA                     2016-10-01
        CL-MF   Fahad  CL-MF                    2016-10-01
        CL-MK   Muhammad Kashif  CL-MK          2016-10-01
        CL-MQ   Qasim  CL-MQ                    2016-10-01
        CL-MS   Saim  CL-MS                     2016-10-01
        CL-MK   Muhammad Kashif  CL-MK  409005  2016-10-01
        CL-MK   Muhammad Kashif  CL-MK  400000  2016-10-01
        CL-MA   Asim  CL-MA             566340  2016-10-01
        CL-MA   Asim  CL-MA             560000  2016-10-01
        CL-MS   Saim  CL-MS             401005  2016-10-01
        CL-MS   Saim  CL-MS             400000  2016-10-01
        CL-MF   Fahad  CL-MF                    2016-10-01
        CL-MQ   Qasim  CL-MQ                    2016-10-01
```

In the Balance column the blank space is equal to null

I am Trying this query to get the minimum balance of every client

```
SELECT idClient,NameClient,min(Balance) from AddClient group by NameClient
```

But Result show like this

```
CL-MA   Asim  CL-MA             560000 
CL-MF   Fahad  CL-MF            3000
CL-MK   Muhammad Kashif  CL-MK  400000
CL-MQ   Qasim  CL-MQ            7000
CL-MS   Saim  CL-MS             1000
```

in Client name Asim and Kashif not show correct result 
the minimum balance of Asim is `8000`and Kashif is `9000`

where is the mistake?

Comment: @dotnetom by mistake its NameClient

Comment: Can you show the CREATE statement? What data type is your `Balance` column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to group both by ID and name of the client instead of grouping only by name:

```
SELECT idClient, NameClient, min(Balance) 
FROM AddClient 
GROUP BY idClient, NameClient
```

Additionally, it seems that the data type that you are using for balance is not a numeric type - that would explain the strange results you are seeing. If the data type is not numeric, you should convert it to numeric type first. Below code assumes that all values in `Balance` column can be converted to integer values, otherwise you will get an exception:

```
SELECT idClient, NameClient, min(CAST(Balance as INTEGER)) 
FROM AddClient 
GROUP BY idClient, NameClient
```

Comment: @jon What data type is `Balance`? I have a feeling it is not a number, is it?

Comment: @jon I added alternative solution in case `Balance` is not a numeric type

Comment: u are right Balance is VARCHAR, now i current this with INTEGER its working. Thank you soooooooo much you are brilliant... Thanks again.